# Is it possible to access characters in a string in R without using strsplit and only basic R functions?

Tags: r

Suppose I had the character vector in R:

```
x <- "hello world"
```

and I wanted to access each element individually. I know that `strsplit` in R can do this, but was wondering if there was a way to access elements without relying on such a function?

Comment: I don't believe that base R supports the string splicing notation which exists in some other languages, such as Python.  So `strsplit()` or maybe a substring call would be the easiest ways to do what you want.

Comment: Does you wish to avoid `strsplit` also rule out `substr`?  Do you wish to access the individual characters in place, or can the original string be manipulated into other forms?

Comment: `strsplit` *is* base R

Comment: By "each element" do you mean each character or the elements of the string after it has been split on a particular character, e.g. spaces? Also if you could explain why you want to do this it would be clearer which functions are in scope - like @Limey my first thought was `substr()` but I don't know if that solves the problem as you haven't said what the problem is...

Comment: Most functions involve `strsplit` in the background, even if another package. You can use various pattern matching functions like `sub()` and extraction like `substr()` and there might be some way to use `strcapture()` (I'm not familiar with it), but in most cases `strsplit` will be the first processing step to then operate on elements of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an alternative, you can use the regular expression. It's a powerful tool that is supported by R.

```
library(tidyverse)
str_extract(x, "\\w+") #you ask to extract each word separated by a space. It includes words or numbers.
#the first \ is to indicate you are using regex.
```

hope this will help